# How to redirect a given short url link to another url just as Vine do

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, http-redirect, codeigniter-routing

I am trying to redirect a Short Url to another Url, For a better understanding

> Consider https://get.vine.co if we paste this on the Desktop Browser we
>   will be redirect to
>   http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/vine/f9e6f07e-e47e-47f5-806d-55d4f79f2b60
>
> In the same way if the same Short Url is called on Mobile device it
>   redirects to Play store or Apple Store.

How Can I achieve this using Codeigniter and PHP.

I assume this is not an anchor tag redirection!!

NOTE: And i am looking for user defined short url.. Which must look like  "https://get.mysite.co"

Kindly put me in some right direction?

Comment: You have to look for the user-agent of the client (http://mobiledetect.net/). That determines the type of user. Next, you will send a redirect header based upon the previously determined user type (https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html - redirect)

Comment: I haven't own a Short Url. Thank you @TomLankhorst I will check this.

Comment: Then you should use a redirect service (https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/) that redirect to a PHP script that does the above. ;)

Comment: Thank you so much @TomLankhorst. Yes I have idea on handling the User agent etc.. The actual part is Short Url.. Thank for the link.

Comment: I want to create a similar url example https://get.mysite.co I dont want google to assign some string

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about codeigniter but in theory you'd have to store the original url along with your short-url hash. Then on a request with that hash you'd have to lookup that hash in DB and simple do a `Location` header to the original url. You could use http://www.hashids.org/ to translate between an auto-increment in your db to a short hash back and forth. That would make your table design a breeze.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Antocom.. But Is is that necessary to save them in DB?

Comment: You could try some fancy compression but IMHO this won't get you anywhere. I'd recommend using the hashids lib with a simple 2-col table: id and url and leverage the hashids-lib to translate between the id and the has you want to use in your short url.